# Locating and modifying Services in OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, services, safari, ios

So, I'd like to be able to add a website viewed in Firefox to the Reading List feature in iOS so I can check stuff on my iPhone. I was inspired by https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51534/reading-list-in-other-browsers but executing a shell script from within a Firefox Addon written in javascript isn't possible (but that's probably a good thing anyway). However, there is a Service that can add an URL to the reading list. It looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/0J1Wvr5]

The service works (obviously), but it opens up Safari, which isn't really something I need.

So in short, I'd like to locate modify the Service so it closes Safari after the URL has been added to the reading list. I tried recreate the Service in Automator, but couldn't find the "add URL to reading list" anywhere.

I've already checked ~/Library/services and /System/Services, no sign of that specific service.

Comment: If you're just looking for where services are stored, look in `/System/Library/Services` or `~/System/Library/Services` (`~/` means your home folder)

Comment: I've alread checked there, no sign of that specific service. Updated the OP.